# Net::SFTP unable to connect via Ruby console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, console, sftp

I am trying to connect to sftp server via ruby console.

Code snippet:::

```
Net::SFTP.start(IP, USERNAME, password: PASS) do |sftp|
.....
end
```

It throws the following error::::

```
Net::SSH::Disconnect: disconnected: No Host (7)
    from /Users/venkatesan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@helpkit/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:188:in `block in poll_message'
    from /Users/venkatesan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@helpkit/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:178:in `loop'
    from /Users/venkatesan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@helpkit/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:178:in `poll_message'
    from /Users/venkatesan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@helpkit/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:163:in `next_message'
    from /Users/venkatesan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@helpkit/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:95:in `block in next_message'
    from /Users/venkatesan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@helpkit/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:94:in `loop'
    from /Users/venkatesan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@helpkit/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:94:in `next_message'
    from /Users/venkatesan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@helpkit/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/none.rb:14:in `authenticate'
    from /Users/venkatesan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@helpkit/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:79:in `block in authenticate'
    from /Users/venkatesan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@helpkit/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/venkatesan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@helpkit/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:66:in `authenticate'
    from /Users/venkatesan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@helpkit/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:211:in `start'
    from /Users/venkatesan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@helpkit/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp.rb:31:in `start'
    from (irb):143
    from /Users/venkatesan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I tried using Net::SSH as well.. Got same error.

But when i do sftp USERNAME and then it prompts for password. It connects properly when i give the password in terminal. But cant connect via ruby code alone.

Can someone throw some light on it?

Comment: What does it mean "when i do sftp USERNAME"? Do you mean command-line `sftp` client? How do you specify the host/IP on command line? If you do just `sftp USERNAME`, you are connecting to a local host.

Comment: Martin,  
  so what i do in terminal is
 sftp <HOST> and it asks for password and it connects on giving it.

if i use the same HOST and password in ruby code, it says "Net::SSH::Disconnect: disconnected: No Host (7)"

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the reason.. I was giving wrong parameter. it was user@host. My parameter was incorrect.

Thanks guys